# Enumerated examples

Tags: lists, theorems

I'm trying to create an example environment, so I've done the very simple

```
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
```

which I can then use as

```
\begin{example}
  Example 1
\end{example}
```

What I would really like to do is (sometimes) have example 12.1(a), 12.1(b), 12.1(c) and then also 12.2,12.3 etc.

Is there a nice simple way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using your theorem definition for examples as a basis, the following MWE provides a `subexample` theorem with a counter of its own that links up with the `example` theorem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newbool{insubexample}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]% Example
\newtheorem{subexample}{Example}[example]% Sub-example
\renewcommand{\thesubexample}{\theexample(\alph{subexample})}%
\AtBeginEnvironment{example}{\global\boolfalse{insubexample}}%
\AtBeginEnvironment{subexample}{%
  \ifbool{insubexample}{}{\global\booltrue{insubexample}%
    \refstepcounter{example}}%
}%
\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{11}% Just because...
\section{A section}
\begin{example}Here's an example.\end{example}
\begin{subexample}Here's a sub-example.\end{subexample}
\begin{subexample}Here's a sub-example.\end{subexample}
\begin{subexample}Here's a sub-example.\end{subexample}
\begin{subexample}Here's a sub-example.\end{subexample}
\begin{example}Here's an example.\end{example}
\begin{example}Here's an example.\end{example}
\begin{subexample}Here's a sub-example.\end{subexample}
\begin{subexample}Here's a sub-example.\end{subexample}
\begin{example}Here's an example.\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example and sub-example theorems]

The [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides support for boolean variables (`insubexample` in this case) that is used to condition on whether or not you are using the regular `example` theorem, or the newly defined `subexample` theorem. Based on this, the regular `example` theorem counter is either incremented or not.